# Flash Media Server & AS3: Publishing works, recording doesn't

Tags: actionscript, flash-media-server, live-streaming

I'm currently having an issue with FMS4 developer edition on both Linux (x64) and Windows XP (x86).

When I stream a webcam using ns.publish("foobar", "live") I can watch the live stream on another client, however when i use ns.publish("foobar", "record"); neither broadcasting nor recording works.

Using the "live" parameter the client appears in the log files and in the administration console as "publishing", using "record" the client appears as "idle".

Is there anything I need to configure besides LIVE_DIR in fms.ini?
Is this a restriction in the developer edition?
Is there something else I'm missing?

Here is the relevant part of the code (condensed):

```
var camLive:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
var ns:NetStream;
nc.connect("rtmp://192.168.1.63/live/");

function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
     if (event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success") {
          ns = new NetStream(nc);
          ns.attachCamera(camLive);
          ns.publish("foobar", "record");
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Fabian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the live application. You can create an empty folder inside "applications", call it "test", then stream to "rtmp://192.168.1.63/test" with parameter "record". According to forums.adobe.com/thread/827134?tstart=0